# criteria for quantaization of excitations in matter

Tags: quantum-mechanics

We know that elementary excitations in plasma, like the free electron gas in a metal, can be quantized. There are known as plasmons. We also know that the elemntary vibrations in the lattice of solids can also be quantized as phonons. My question is two fold.

1. What is the critera for quantaiztion?
2. These so called quasi-particels do not really exist, but these excitations can be treated, at least mathematically, as particles. What is the property or feature that makes the physics or math work.

Comment: For basic stuff like this you really need to go off and do some Googling

Comment: Well firstly, whenever you have a 'small' system, quantum mechanics will surely come to play. So the scale of things has a great deal to do with quantization. On other hand, quantization can be used to describe discreetness on a small scale, quantum is the smallest amount of something that can interact (light quanta or photon etc.). For quasiparticles question, I think that it's just that you see that it's easier to describe that phenomena with the same mathematics that you describe real particles, so you use it, with some additional assumptions.